# Block the access of Aws cloudfront url from chrome, safari and all browsers

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

**Had Done:**

1. I had done uploading Kyc documents and attachments in s3 bucket
2. Integrated S3 with CloudFront
3. Blocked all public access in S3 bucket.
4. Only way of accessing content is 'CloudFront url'

**My requirement is:**

1. Any one can access the documents if 'CloudFront Url' known
2. So i want to *restrict the access of URL* except my application
3. Mainly block the **access of that url** in **chrome, safari** and **all browsers**

Is it possible to restrict the URL ? How ?

Answer (score 1):

[Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) will let you do almost anything you want with a request as it's processed by CloudFront.

You could look at the user agent, then return a 403 if it doesn't match what you expect. Beware, however, that it's not difficult to change the user-agent string. Better is to use an authentication token.

Comment: Yeah I completely agree, it seems like they need to implement authentication/authorization to truly solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't understand your question well and you should make an attempt to describe the issue again. From a bird's eye view, I feel you are describing an IDOR vulnerability. But I will address multiple parts in my response.

AWS WAF will allow you to perform quite a bit of blocking on a wide variety of request content.

Specifically for this problem, if you choose to use AWS WAF, you can do the following to address this issue:

1. Create a WAF ACL, it should not be regional and should be global, set the default action of the WAF ACL to auto allow
2. Build regex pattern sets of what you would like to block or you can hard code specific examples
3. Create a rule that will block requests which have a `User-Agent` header that matches your regex pattern set

But at the end of the day, you might just be fighting a battle which should not necessarily be fought in the first place. Think about it like this, if you want to block all `User-Agent` headers which symbolize a browser, that is fine. But the problem is, the `User-Agent` header can easily be overwritten and spoofed such you won't see the typical browser `User-Agent` header. I don't suggest you to block requests based on this criteria because at the end of the day, I can just use a proxy and have it replace that request content before forwarding the traffic to the server and bypass the WAF or even Lambda@Edge.

What I would suggest is to develop some sort of authorization/authentication requirement to access these specific files. Since KYC can be sensitive, this would be a good control to put in place  to be sure the files are not accessed by those who should not access them.

It seems to me like you are running into a case where an attacker can exploit an IDOR vulnerability. If that is the case, you need to program this logic in the application layer. There will be no way to prevent this at the AWS WAF layer.

If you truly wanted to fix the issue and you were dealing with an IDOR, I would use Lambda@Edge to validate that the `Cookie` included in the request should be able to access the KYC document. You should store in a database what KYC documents can be accessed by which specific user and you should check that the `Cookies` header includes the `Cookies` of the user who uploaded the KYC document. This would be effectively implementing authorization/authentication, but instead at just at the application layer, it would be also at the Lambda@Edge (or CDN) layer.